# design database for class with groups and students

Tags: database

I'm trying to design database for a class, in each class has many group or none, and each group has many student. [image]

I drew two entity relation diagram like this.
For diagram 1 circle relation appear.
For diagram 2 to add student into class i have to add group so if class don't have group then i will can't add student into class. How can i design database for this situation ?

Comment: Questions: 1. Can 1 student belong to more than 1 group ? 2. Can a student belong to no group ?

Comment: question 1: current: no, in future maybe, question 2: yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first diagram doesn't have circular functional dependencies.  Read them from the "many" side to the "one" side:

```
Student -> Group (Belong to)
Student -> Group (Manage)
Group -> Student (Manage)
Group -> Class (Has)
Student -> Class (Belong to)
```

Class doesn't determine Student or Group, so there are no cyclic "references".

Circular relationships can be a warning that you need to watch out for possible anomalies - in this case, take care that students can't be associated with different classes via the two paths from Student to Class.  As long as you take care that your data remains valid, circular relationships aren't a problem.

For your second diagram, you could adopt the convention that every class has at least one group (i.e. if there are no subgroups, the whole class counts as a group).  In this way, every student is associated with a class via their group and you don't need to record that association directly.

Comment: I would rather say the diagram is ambiguous on this point.  It would be risky to implement the database straight from the ER diagram, traditionally one would prepare a physical model first to ensure it implements all the logical requirements.  There are ways to handle integrity in the physical implementation (i.e. via denormalization and composite FK constraints) that would mitigate the issue while allowing the association to be recorded directly.

Answer (score 0):

These should be the tables in your DB:

1. Class table: Primary key would be ClassId.
2. Student table: Primary key Would be StudentId and FK(foreign key) would be ClassId.
3. Group table: Primary key would be GroupId, it would contain ClassId as FK.
4. Groups_Student table:  This table contains the mapping of groups and students. So FK will be GroupId and StudentId.

The above design supports a student belonging to multiple groups or no groups at all. This assumes that a group is just associated with a single class. This also assumes that a student is just associated with a single class.

Comment: Your implementation covers most of diagram 1 (except the Manage relationship) but doesn't address the circular relation confusion, explain why you prefer diagram 1 over diagram 2, or warn about the possibility of anomalies.

Comment: Thanks for following up. The manage relationShip (which is 1:1) can be captured by keeping the "ManagingStudentId" in the Group table.  Regarding 1 vs 2, I preferred 1 because it supports the idea of a student belonging to a class, without belonging to a group. I don't see a true circular relationship that we need to circumvent.